# Who were the hooded people in The Rise of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

Near the end of *Star Wars Episode IX: The Rise of Skywalker* there are several hooded figures that are shown chanting stuff (in Sith?) and just hanging out with Palpatine. Who were these people?

Comment: The implication I took from it was that they were force projections of all the previous Sith (tying into the "I carry all of them in me" thing they suddenly pulled out of their...um...script).

Comment: Early on in the movie you see hooded creatures in the scene where Palpatine meets Kylo, I assumed these where the same creatures that built the massive space fleet and so they get a grandstand view of there new boss being created.

Comment: That scene seemed similar to the one from the game Star Wars, Knights of the Old Republic II, where Atris is in a Sith chamber and you hear similar chanting sounds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They seem to have been the "[Sith Eternal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith_Eternal)", a cultist order who followed the Sith, according to the Visual Dictionary. They're mentioned earlier in the movie as "Sith Loyalists" and helped build the Final Order fleet.

Comment: How did they all get to Exagon?

Comment: @Möoz I believe they live there, as they worship the sith. The unknown regions being unpopulated is a misconception it seems. Plenty of sith loyalists who'll build things and serve palpatine.

Comment: Is it confirmed that they are the same guys who appear during final battle at the end of the movie? I was sure that they were some sith ghosts then

Comment: @Thamiar - They couldn't have been ghosts as the movie makes it a point to show them being crushed by the falling temple or whatever that building was at the end.