# Who was on the audience during final battle in Rise of the Skywalker

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

I watched the film twice, and still, I am unsure who was on the audience during battle between Palpatine and Ray+Kylo?
I thought they are some kind of ancient sith ghosts, while friend of my insist on the version, that the hooded characters are the same as the ones who repaired Kylo's helmet. (Some sort of Palpatines cult?)
Is there any canonical answer to that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who were the hooded people in The Rise of Skywalker?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/224878/who-were-the-hooded-people-in-the-rise-of-skywalker)

Comment: Well, almost. I mean it explains who are those cultists. I was asking if at the final battle we see those cultist or some sith ghosts.

Comment: We saw only hooded characters, while at the beginning of the film, cultists had faces. That is the question, the characters at the final battle and cultists from the beginning are the same?